# Unpivot dataframe in Python - 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, pandas, unpivot

I unpivoted a dataframe:

[image]

Like this:

```
full_unpivot = full.unstack.reset_index(name='Value')
full_unpivot.rename(columns={'level_0': 'Attribute', 'level_1': 'Scenario'}, inplace=True)
```

[image]

Now I wanted to drop decimals in values and add a column filled with 1 or -1 depending on the sign of the 'value' column.
However when I try to do:

```
full_unpivot = full_unpivot.applymap(np.int64)
```

or 
list='Value'

```
full_unpivot[list] = full_unpivot[list].astype(int)
```

or

```
full_unpivot = full_unpivot.insert(4,'sign',1)
```

I get an error:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem.. ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
full_unpivot['sign'] = np.sign(full_unpivot['value'])
```

Problem in your code should be used variable `list`, what is code word.

Solution should be reassign to `builtins`:

```
list = builtins.list
```

Also if want use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to second column called `sign` filled values of function `np.sign` use:

```
full_unpivot.insert(1,'sign',np.sign(full_unpivot['value']))
```

Comment: Thanks! Im still getting the same error... Im thinking that maybe Python doesnt recognize the new full unpivot dataframe as a dataframe - as it was computed by some method .. ?

Comment: @user10484829 - what is print (type(full_unpivot)) before row of code which raise error? Maybe you forget some `()` like `mean()` - `mean`